# usar bootstrap janela modal sobreposta

Tags: modal

Bom dia, amigos.
Estou usando um botão para chamar uma janela modal bootstrap...até aí sem problemas. Dentro dessa janela modal tenho outro botão que chama uma segunda janela modal...funciona perfeitamente. O problema é que ao voltar para primeira janela, a mesma fica travada e não consigo rolar ela (ela ultrapassa a altura do monitor); somente o que está em segundo plano (embaixo da primeira janela modal) é que roda. Só consigo sair da primeira janela modal teclando esc. 
Só pra constar, eu uso o atributo "data-backdrop='static' para não fechar a janela clicando fora dela e obrigar o usuário a clicar no botão 'fechar' para sair da primeira janela modal .
Alguém sabe disse o que está errado ? Estou postando abaixo o código:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="cxEditaEvento" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-focus-on="input:first">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title text-left" id="myModalLabel">Dados do Evento</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="formEditaEvento" id="formEditaEvento" name="formEditaEvento" method="POST" action="saveEvento.php">
                    <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="showID">ID</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="showID" id="showID" disabled />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="atividade">Evento</label>
                        <select class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow" data-width="260px" name="atividade" autofocus >
                            <?php 
                                if($stmt_atividades->rowCount() > 0){
                                    foreach($vetAtividades as $chave => $valor){
                                        echo "<option value='" . $vetAtividades[$chave]['ID'] . "'";
                                        echo ">" . $vetAtividades[$chave]['DESCRICAO'] . "</option>";
                                    }
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                        <button type='button' id='btnNovaAtividade' class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' title='clique para inserir' data-toggle='modal' data-zero='cadSolicit' href='#cxEditaAtividade'>Novo</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="complemento">Atividade</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="complemento" id="complemento" placeholder="Complemento" value="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="numparticip">Participantes</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="numparticip" id="numparticip" placeholder="Informe o nº estimado" value="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="observ">Obs</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" cols="80" name="observ" id="observ" placeholder="Observações" /></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-actions">
                        <button type="submit" name="btnSaveEvento" value="btnSaveEvento" id="btnSaveEvento" class="btn btn-primary btn-large pull-left">Salvar</button>
                    </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div id="loadEditaEvento"><img src="Imagens/ajax-loader.gif" /></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div id="resultEditaEvento"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="btnFecharCaixaEditaEvento" class="btn btn-default btnCloseModal" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="cxEditaAtividade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title text-left" id="myModalLabel">Descrição do Evento / Atividade</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="formEditaAtividade" id="formEditaAtividade" name="formEditaAtividade" method="POST" action="saveAtividade.php">
                    <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="showID">ID</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="showID" id="showID" disabled />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="descricao">Nome</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="descricao" id="descricao" placeholder="Informe a descrição para a atividade" value="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-actions">
                        <button type="submit" name="enviar" value="enviar" class="btn btn-primary btn-large pull-left">Salvar</button>
                    </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div id="loadEditaAtividade"><img src="Imagens/ajax-loader.gif" /></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div id="resultEditaAtividade"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema com o código abaixo:

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () { 
    $('.modal:visible').length && $(document.body).addClass('modal-open');
});
```

Com isso a janela modal volta a rolar normalmente e não o segundo plano.

Espero que ajude.